# Slide dynamically added content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm trying to create a simple content slider that could handle dynamically added content to the slider. None of the "lightweight" plugins I found provided such functionality or, if it did, it didn't work correctly.

```
var $left = $('.left'),
    $right = $('.right'),
    $months = $('.sub ul');


$left.click(function(){
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        $months.find('li').first().before($.parseHTML('<li>xxx</li>'));   
    }
    pos = $months.position();
    $months.css('left', pos.left + 90);
});

$right.click(function(){
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        $months.find('li').last().after($.parseHTML('<li>xxx</li>'));   
    }
    pos = $months.position();
    $months.css('left', pos.left - 90);
});
```

This is the code I've got so far and here's a fiddle with an example - http://jsfiddle.net/kkr4zg0r/2/. It kind of works, but the problem is that since new content is added the navigation goes off (you can see what I mean by clicking left-right a couple of times).

I understand what's the problem for this - the newly added items "shift" the content and I need to do better calculations than substracting/adding 90px to the left position of the element but I can't figure out how to get the correct index of the elements and basically get this sliding by exactly (and correctly) by 3(or 6) elements at the time.
Currently the code is adding extra elements whenever a navigation button is pressed, if I could get the index of the currently visible first/last element, I could probably tell whether I need to add more elements and only add them then.

This is a basic illustration of what I'm trying to achieve
[image: illustration]

**edit**
I've changed the jsfiddle to the correct one.

Comment: could you get more specific on what you want to achieve? i understand your fiddle, and also see the navigation going out of bounds due to your code - but still i don't get the point, how you want your slider to be...

Comment: I want the slider to be able to scroll through months back and forth and the new, unloaded months to be added dynamically. It will jump between years as well. Currently there is no indication which years months are being shown since that will be added later.

Comment: okay... got the point... since there is already a solution, and i have to leave now... i'll leave it as is... but if you want me to, i'll provide another solution, without repositioning the slides - and also only load new ones, if need be... tomorrow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole idea is to check when adding elements is necessary and when shift is enough:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkr4zg0r/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var $main = $('.main'),
        $left = $('.left'),
        $right = $('.right'),
        $months = $('.sub ul');

    var addCount = 3;
    var liWidth = 30;
    var shiftX = addCount * liWidth;

    $left.click(function()
    {
        var currentLeft = parseInt($months.css('left'));
        var totalLength = $months.find('li').length * liWidth;
        if (-currentLeft + $main.width() >= totalLength)
        {   
            for (var i = 0; i < addCount; i++)
            {
                $months.find('li:last').after('<li>xxx</li>');   
            }
        }
        $months.css('left', currentLeft -= shiftX);
    });

    $right.click(function()
    {
        var currentLeft = parseInt($months.css('left'));
        if (currentLeft < 0)
        {
            $months.css('left', currentLeft += shiftX);
        }
        else
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < addCount; i++)
            {
                $months.find('li:first').before('<li>xxx</li>');   
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Works exactly as I intended it to be. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @EliahJohn you're welcome. But there is a bug with `$left` (adding unnecessary `<li>`), so please check for update in several minutes.

Comment: @EliahJohn finally it works as it is supposed to work.